# Facebook SDK for android: getFirstName() and getLastName() return null strings

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developing an android native app using Facebook SDK 3.5.

I'm trying to have an autocompletetextview where I can pick some facebook friends, for this I'm using an newMyFriendsRequest as below:

```
private void fbFriendsRequest(final Session session) {
    Request request = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> listFacebookFriends, Response response) {
            // If the response is successful
            if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                if (listFacebookFriends != null) {
                    mAdapter = new GraphUserAdapter(FriendPicker.this, listFacebookFriends);
                    mAutoComplete.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    Toast.makeText(FriendPicker.this,"Friends Loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            if (response.getError() != null) {
                // Handle errors, will do so later.
            }
        }
    });
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Then each time the user pick a row from the autocompletetextview I add this row to another list, and when a I press OK button I have:

```
public void onOkClick(View v) {
    if(mGraphUsersList.size()==0) {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,null);    
    } else {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        Iterator<GraphUser> itr = mGraphUsersList.iterator();
        int n = mGraphUsersList.size();
        String[] idfb = new String[n];
        String[] names = new String[n];
        String[] lastnames = new String[n];
        int i = 0;
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            GraphUser User = (GraphUser) itr.next();
            idfb[i]=User.getId();
            names[i]=User.getFirstName();    // problem
            lastnames[i]=User.getLastName(); // problem
            i++;
        }
        returnIntent.putExtra("idfb",idfb);
        returnIntent.putExtra("names",names);
        returnIntent.putExtra("lastnames",lastnames);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
    }
    finish();
}
```

When I use the getFirstName() and getLastName() functions I have null strings, but if I use getName() function it's return the name+lastname. It's like if in the list given by newMyFriendsRequest something has been lost.

Anyone knows a workaround for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get other fields than `id` and `name` of friends, you need to specify them explicitly in your request.

For this add them to the `Bundle` of your request like:

```
Request request = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> listFacebookFriends, Response response) {
        // your code like you did
    }
}

// here add fields explicitly 
Bundle bundle = request.getParameters();
mBundle.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name");

// execute like you did
request.executeAsync();
```

This is one solution for you, or **another one** is to use this super simple library: [android-simple-facebook](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook)

Comment: Thank you! I've changed a little bit the code with: `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name");
  request.setParameters(bundle);`

Comment: @sromku where to find this kind of information regarding Facebook SDK ? How can one know what's default available and what needs to added explicitly ?

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo I am afraid to say, that there is no such information. I think that I read 99% of all their docs. I found this by playing a lot with graph api explorer. For example if you run `/me/friends` you will get only `id` and `name` for your friends. Also, saw many code samples that do the same. Maybe one day, facebook will have better documentation to cover this info.

Comment: @sromku Thanks for the info. I also took a look at your github library. It seems very useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    Log.d("fbEmail_id", profile.getFirstName());
                    String first_name=profile.getFirstName();
                    String last_name=profile.getLastName();
                }
```

Comment: HI! where is `Profile` coming from? Please add some comments/explanation to your code for clarity.